# Loading a single file for all pages

Tags: php, apache

I am running a Apache webserver, my goal is to have a loader (In PHP) that gets loaded from all URLs. For example if you head to website.com/test/, website.com/page.php or just website.com/ it will always load website.com/index.php

How can i achieve this?

Comment: You need to look into [URL rewriting with apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a .htaccess file that will rewrite the URL for anything this is not a file or directory on your server and redirect it to the `index.php` file.  Additionally you can have the original URL attached as the query string so you can work with it in your script if need be.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a .htaccess file with the following lines and put it in the root directory of your website:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

If a .htaccess file already exists, you can try appending those lines if there's no conflicting rules.